# Riding PVTA buses (in Amherst)

Tags: usa, public-transport, buses, massachusetts

From https://www.umass.edu/transportation/how-much-bus-fare:

> Bus drivers will not collect fares/passes, but passengers are expected to have either a valid Five College student, faculty or staff ID cards or a fare ticket/pass for each ride.

From http://www.pvta.com/fares.php:

> Bus Fares - When using cash, exact change is required.
>
> Adults 13 and older - $1.50
>
> $1.40 if purchased at the Customer Service Center.

The first source says that one has to buy some ticket in order to ride a bus and that bus drivers will not collect fares, but the second source implies that one can pay in cash. So can I use cash to ride a bus? Or do I need to buy a ticket at the Customer Service Center (if so, what's its location)?

Comment: My guess is that the first link means drivers will not *actively* collect fares or demand to see passes.  If you have a pass, you just get on.  If you don't, then you have to go up to the driver and pay cash, and they'll accept your payment and give you a ticket or some other proof of payment.  Either way, it's up to you to do the right thing without being asked; there may be "spot checks" that will catch people who don't have a pass and haven't paid.

Comment: The service centre address is given at the bottom of the fares page you linked to. You can also find it, along with contact phone numbers and a map on the [customer service](http://www.pvta.com/customerService.php) page

Comment: It would be ridiculous to go from Amherst to Springfield to visit the service center with the purpose of buying a ticket for a bus operating in Amherst.